# How to append new value to the existing.... object of arraylist c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
var sid = (from transaction in doc.Descendants("transaction")
           from tenderdetails in transaction.Elements("tenderdetail")
           where (int)tenderdetails.Element("tendertype") == 13

           select new
           {
               storeID = (string)transaction.Element("storeid"),
           }).Distinct();



al.AddRange((from transaction in doc.Descendants("transaction")
             from tenderdetails in transaction.Elements("tenderdetail")
             where (int)tenderdetails.Element("tendertype") == 13

             select new
             {
                 tendertype = (string)tenderdetails.Element("tendertype"),
                 storeID = (int)transaction.Element("storeid"),
                 tDate = (string)transaction.Element("date"),
                 sTime = Convert.ToString(vdt.GetValidDateTime((string)transaction.Element("time")) + ".000"),
                 etime = Convert.ToString(vdt.GetValidDateTime((string)transaction.Element("endTime")) + ".000"),
                 strans = vdt.GetValidDate((string)transaction.Element("date"), "yyyymmdd") + " " + Convert.ToString(vdt.GetValidDateTime((string)transaction.Element("time")) + ".000"),
                 etrans = vdt.GetValidDate((string)transaction.Element("date"), "yyyymmdd") + " " + Convert.ToString(vdt.GetValidDateTime((string)transaction.Element("endTime")) + ".000"),
                 totalAmount = (string)transaction.Element("totalamt"),
              ).ToList());
```

Result:

> tendertype = 13, storeID = 1830020, tDate = 20180628, sTime = 13:30:36.000, etime = 13:30:40.000, strans = 2018-06-28 13:30:36.000, etrans = 2018-06-28 13:30:40.000, totalAmount = 4700 }{ tendertype = 13, storeID = 1830020, tDate = 20180628, sTime = 15:35:15.000, etime = 15:35:23.000, strans = 2018-06-28 15:35:15.000, etrans = 2018-06-28 15:35:23.000, totalAmount = 3400 }

My question is can I append some more value to these arraylist object

Comment: What is the question? Please explain in more detail what is it that you want.

Comment: I have a arraylist populated with result, what I want is to append more values to the array object. Ths this the array object result tendertype = 13, storeID = 1830020, tDate = 20180628, sTime = 13:30:36.000, etime = 13:30:40.000, strans = 2018-06-28 13:30:36.000, etrans = 2018-06-28 13:30:40.000, totalAmount = 4700 }   what to append more values like this tendertype = 13, storeID = 1830020, tDate = 20180628, sTime = 13:30:36.000, etime = 13:30:40.000, strans = 2018-06-28 13:30:36.000, etrans = 2018-06-28 13:30:40.000, totalAmount = 4700, append value 1 , append value 2 }

Comment: If you want to add more objects to the arraylist,call al.Add or al.AddRange multiple times?

Comment: Which kind of objects you want to add with? Try using `Add()` method (and I suggest you to change into `var` on query assignment instead of explicitly declaring `ArrayList`).